# Can stair stringers overhang landing?

Tags: stairs

I'm building a new set of stairs up to a deck. The concrete landing for the stairs is less than 3 feet wide and has a fence along the opposite side from the stairs.

I basically have 2 options that would give me acceptable run and rise measurements:

1. have the bottom of the stringers fully resting on the landing about 2 or 3 inches in from the back edge or...
2. have about half the bottom of the stringers overhanging the back edge of the landing.

In the first example (see figure 1) it would only leave about 1 1/2 feet from the front edge of the stringers to the fence.

In the second example (see figure 2), the run is approximately 12 inches and about 5 and 1/2 inches would be overhanging the back edge of the landing giving me an extra 7 or 8 inches of landing.

[image]

Comment: Building a stair that dead ends into a fence with only a foot or two of landing seems kind of broken. You should consider some other options such as adding a suitable landing off the edge of the deck at the top and then turn the stair ninety degrees so it comes down parallel to the fence.

Comment: Or, get really fancy and put a 90° turn in the stairs with a landing mid-way down. However, @MichaelKaras' is a better/easier proposition.

Comment: Don’t you need 3’ at the bottom of the staircase? I might be thinking of a landing at top.  I would probably do a 90 like Michael suggests.

Comment: @MichaelKaras, yes, it's not an ideal situation and a 90° turn would be the best solution but it's not possible due to the layout of the surrounding area. I'm replacing a preexisting set of stairs which have rotted out at the base of the stringers. The stairs are rarely used so I could probably do away with them altogether but have decided to go ahead and replace them anyway.

Comment: Can you shorten the run anymore to get as close to 3 ft at the landing if you added a bearing surface in front of the existing slab? I typically use masonry lintels for this

Comment: No, unfortunately that's not possible based on the current layout of the deck.